# CakePHP Validate only if supplied

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, passwords

In my 'Members' model, I am comparing whether `password` matches `password_confirm` through this custom validation key/function pair.

```
...'password_confirm' => array(
        'compare'    => array(
            'rule'      => array('validate_passwords'),
            'message'   => 'The passwords you entered do not match.',
            'required'  => true
        ),

        'length' => array(
            'rule'      => array('between', 6, 20),
            'message'   => 'Your password must be between 6 and 20 characters.',
        ),

        'empty' => array(
            'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
            'message'   => 'The password field must not be left blank.',
        ),
    )...
```

function validate_passwords...

```
function validate_passwords($data, $password_field = 'password', $hashed = true) {
    $password         = $this->data['Member']['password'];
    $password_confirm = $hashed ?
          Security::hash($data['password_confirm'], null, true) :
          $data['password_confirm'];
    return $password === $password_confirm;
}
```

I have many different sections of my site that allow the editing of members. Some sections allow for passwords to be changed, and others just let members edit their bio.

However, because there's no `password_confirm` field in the form where users edit their bio (for example) the validation **always returns false** on any form, other than forms which have `password_confirm` present.

Is there an efficient way to validate like this...

"Compare password with password_confirm only if the `password_confirm` key exists in the `$data` array"

I couldn't find this anywhere on SO, I hope I am not repeating an existing question.

Thanks!

NB. I want to make sure that the field hasn't been left blank if it does exist in the form.

Comment: use allowEmpty as true for confirm password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
'allowEmpty' => true
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1148/allowEmpty

The cookbook ^^^

http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/validation_difference_between_allowempty_flag_and_notempty_rule

Some discussion about empty validation tests. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify your `validate_passwords` function do return true if the `['password_confirm']` field does not exist.

If it does exist, check do see if it's `empty()` first (if so, return false).

lastly do the rest of your checking as it currently is.

Comment: Fixed that section, thanks, but now I have the problem with the built-in rules, whereby it's checking password length, even though I haven't supplied a password to it to be changed.

Comment: you will probably have to create a custom length checking function then too.